# Adding custom event handling loop to Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is this an okay thing to do?

```
from tkinter import *;
from tkinter import ttk;
import keyboard;


root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Meters")

################# custom event handling loop
while True:
    keyboard.wait('space');
    print('space was pressed! Waiting on it again...');
#################


root.mainloop()
```

The code runs fine so far I'm just wondering if I should expect troubles in the long run.

Comment: When asking a question, stick to it. Don't use the same question to ask different questions. Please take the [tour] and consider to read [ask].

Comment: @Ben the Coder: Good job on the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `while True` loop will block the main thread, meaning you can't do anything else while it is running which is not ideal. Instead, use `root.bind`

```
def callback(event):
    print('space was pressed! Waiting on it again...')

root.bind('<space>', callback)
```

This will run `callback` whenever you press space. `event` is provided by Tkinter and contains more information about the keypress event.

Unlike your current method `bind` will only work when the window has focus. If this is a problem, use threading instead.

```
import threading

def wait_space():
    while True:
        keyboard.wait('space');
        print('space was pressed! Waiting on it again...')

threading.Thread(target = wait_space).start()
```

This will run the `while True` loop in another thread, meaning the main thread can continue working.

Comment: I actually use the other thing. I edited the code. From keyboard pypi module web page "Events automatically captured in separate thread, doesn't block main program.". So i guess if i put event handling in the separate thread thats totally okay?

Comment: Your edited code should work fine.